# How do i find the css selector for a Text message

Tags: css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need to find the css selector for the text message : Congratulations! displayed after the registration form is filled successfully by a new user. I am using Selenium Web driver to automate the registration process. I have to assert  "Congratulations,Your email has been verified" text. Below is the HTML code for the same :

```
<div class="d-title">
<h1>Congratulations!</h1>
<strong>Your e-mail address has been verified.</strong>
```

Thanks,
Java Beginner

Answer (score 1):

You can't match on text in CSS.  You can do it in XPath, but CSS does not have a selector that matches a text node.  In XPath, it would be simple: `//div/h1[. = 'Congratulations!']`.

Answer (score 1):

The below code will wait for 10 seconds and check if the selector contains the provided text, if it doesnt contain, an exception will be thrown...If you want to handle the exception, just surround it with try and catch

```
new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElement(By.cssSelector("div.d-title>h1"),"Congratulations,Your email has been verified"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since, `Congratulations!` and `Your e-mail address has been verified.` are two different texts, you will have to user two different css selectors for them:

For `Congratulations!`, use `div.d-title > h1`

For `Your e-mail address has been verified.`, use `div.d-title > strong`